# Listening on port 22

Tags: linux, ssh, port

Is there any way to listen in on port 22, on my server, to see if anyone submitted any commands while ssh'd into my server? Or rather, output what commands were submitted (and the ip address of who connected), almost like a 'live' log?

Answer (score 1):

```
strace -o trace -f -p PID_OF_SSH # will give lots of output and very low level
```

Comment: This must be run as root or the user who owns the SSH process on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The `auth.log` file should have a history of SSH logins (enabled by default).

If you're running SSH on port 22 you should have extreme password requirements or use SSH Keys and disable password authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely. If you have ssh running on port 22 ([as it's intended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)), then the communications are encrypted.

[w](http://man.cx/w) or [who](http://man.cx/who) or [last](http://man.cx/last) will let you see who is connected.

If they're logging their commands to a history, then you could inspect their history files.

Also, this should be on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: So I couldn't see who is connected and what commands they are submitting? On my server?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, but my question still stands

Comment: Not by listening on port 22, no.

Comment: You can see who's connected.  See: [w](http://man.cx/w) or [who](http://man.cx/who) or [last](http://man.cx/last).  If they're logging their commands to a history, then you could inspect their history files.

Comment: You say not by listening, so is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use process accounting to keep a detailed log of commands run on your server.

On Debian:

```
apt-get install acct
```

Then use `lastcomm` to see who ran what at what time. `lastcomm --help` lists several ways to get information, including filtering by user, command or tty.

You can use `last` to figure out which virtual terminal (for example pts/9) was assigned to the ssh session you're interested in. Then, continuing with the example, run:

```
lastcomm pts/9
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn up the logging on your SSH daemon.

```
 LogLevel
         Gives the verbosity level that is used when logging messages from
         sshd.  The possible values are: QUIET, FATAL, ERROR, INFO, VER-
         BOSE, DEBUG, DEBUG1, DEBUG2 and DEBUG3.  The default is INFO.
         DEBUG and DEBUG1 are equivalent.  DEBUG2 and DEBUG3 each specify
         higher levels of debugging output.  Logging with a DEBUG level
         violates the privacy of users and is not recommended.
```

Comment: Actually, logging with DEBUG and higher levels outputs quite a bit of information but I haven't ever seen it logging the commands run. Are you sure about this?